# indentkey '}' triggers with delay?

Tags: indentation

I have several indentkeys (like `end`, `elseif`...), all of the works fine but typing `}` triggers the reindentation with a 1s delay. It behaves the same if I disabled my `'indentexpr'` and use `'cindent'`.

Comment: first, you can check if `}` in insert mode has been mapped, via `:imap }`.

Comment: @WangShidong It's not, `}` is inserted immediately it's just the reindentation is triggered with delay

Comment: I found the problem, it's `'showmatch'`, if I disabled it the delay is gone, should be a bug?

Comment: @wengwengweng showmatch is known to cause some delays. I too have disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

The delay is caused by `'showmatch'` and `'matchtime'`

`:set noshowmatch` or `:set matchtime=0` negates the delay.